# Which is the song played in episode #119 when Asta stabs the demon's heart at the end of the episode?

Tags: music, black-clover

In episode #119, at the end of it, Asta stabs the demon's heart, meanwhile a song is played . What's the name of this song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the Opening「Haruka Mirai」by Kankaku Piero.

Here’s a link straight to the song https://youtu.be/7WKCUxKa-k8